# C# Progress Bar Invoke/Delegate issue

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm transfering files and would like a progress bar to show the actually progress of each file.  This is working fine for files under 15 megs but files greater than that seem to cause my applicaiton to freeze.  If I don't call this code for the progress bar, these larger files transfer just fine.

I've tried all sorts of different ways to handle this with delegates but no luck.  Rather, they work fine with smaller files but not larger ones.

Some examples that worked...

```
pbFileProgress.Invoke((MethodInvoker)
   delegate 
   { 
      pbFileProgress.Value = args.PercentDone;
   });
```

Also, this collection of methods worked for smaller files.

```
private delegate void SetProgressBarCallback(int percentDone);

public void UpdateProgressBar(object send, UploadProgressArgs args)
{
   if (pbFileProgress.InvokeRequired)
   {
      var d = new SetProgressBarCallback(ProgressBarUpdate);
      BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { args.PercentDone });
   }
   else
   {
      ProgressBarUpdate(args.PercentDone);
   }
}

public void ProgressBarUpdate(int percentDone)
{
   pbFileProgress.Value = percentDone;
}
```

But again, everything just freezes if I try larger files.

Comment: Where's the code that copies the file? And how do you do the threading?

Comment: Please include the code where you calculate the percent completed. Since your problem is related to the size of the download, most likely you are attempting to update the progress bar too frequently (e.g. you're downloading 10 bytes at a time and updating the progress bar each time; this would work OK for a 100 byte file, but fail for a 15 MB file).

Comment: @MusiGenesis The OP did state files under 15MB, which would hopefully imply greater than 100 bytes but could still be the root cause.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the BackgroundWorker? This functionality exists within that class and makes what you are trying to do trivial. Not to say it can't be done without the BackgroundWorker, I am just trying to understand why?

Comment: @AaronMcIver: I used made-up numbers to illustrate the potential problem. Hopefully nobody would ever try downloading 10 bytes at a time.

Comment: I didn't include the code for the actual file transfer, because all its doing setting the UploadProgressEvent of a TransferRequest (Amazon S3 stuff) to the method.

Comment: This is a side-effect of calling BeginInvoke() too often, the UI thread doesn't get around to doing its low priority tasks anymore.  Like painting and responding to user input.  Throttle it so it doesn't happen more often than about 25 times per second.  Looks smooth to the human eye.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the lack of context, here's an example that work. The BeginInvoke or Invoke method is called only 100 times max.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      using (var source = File.OpenRead(@"D:\Temp\bbe.wav"))
      using (var destination = File.Create(@"D:\Temp\Copy.wav"))
      {
         var blockUnit = source.Length / 100;

         var total = 0L;
         var lastValue = 0;

         var buffer = new byte[4096];
         int count;

         while ((count = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
         {
            destination.Write(buffer, 0, count);

            total += count;

            if (blockUnit > 0 && total / blockUnit > lastValue)
            {
               this.BeginInvoke(
                  new Action<int>(value => this.progressBar1.Value = value),
                  lastValue = (int)(total / blockUnit));
            }
         }

         this.BeginInvoke(
            new Action<int>(value => this.progressBar1.Value = value), 100);
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is very common when communicating between background and foreground threads: the background thread is sending the foreground thread **too many** updates.

The foreground thread handles updating, drawing, and user input, so when too many updates come in, the UI freezes trying to catch up.
Obviously, if the background thread continues to send updates, the foreground can be backed up even *after* the background task finishes!

There are several solutions to this problem, but my strongest recommendation is to use a `Timer` in the foreground thread to **poll** the background progress and update the UI.
The advantage of using a `Timer`:

- The background thread can report the progress as frequently as needed
- The foreground thread can just relax until an update is needed
- The foreground thread will not "back up" with updates
- If the foreground thread is "resting", then the background thread gets more processor time
- The frequency of the `Timer` can be set to a "reasonable" value, such as 250ms (4 updates per second), so that progress is smooth but doesn't take the whole processor

As always, thread safety is important when communicating the progress between threads.  Using a simple 32-bit `int` value is thread-safe in this scenario, but using a 64-bit `double` is not thread safe on 32-bit machines.

Answer (score 0):

You could Invoke based on the UI element.  For example:

```
private delegate void InvokeUpdateProgressBar(object send, UploadProgressArgs args);
private int _PercentDone = -1;

public void UpdateProgressBar(object send, UploadProgressArgs args)
{
   if(_PercentDone != args.PercentDone)
   {
      if (pbFileProgress.InvokeRequired)
      {
         pbFileProgress.Invoke(
            new InvokeUpdateProgressBar(UpdateProgressBar),
            new object[] { send, args });
      }
      else
      {
         ProgressBarUpdate(args.PercentDone);
      }
      _PercentDone = args.PercentDone;
   }
}
```

Otherwise I would suggest what Aaron McIver did and use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.
See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204839/95573) for details on updating a progressbar using the BackgroundWorker class

**Update**
Looks like you are not the only one with this issue.  See [Amazon s3 Transferutility.Upload hangs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362049/amazon-s3-transferutility-upload-hangs-in-c-sharp) here.  Kent also points says: `If you read in about the S3 forums you'll find many people having similar issues`

Comment: I tried this method exactly, no dice, same problem. App locks up on larger files.
I'm not clear how to implement the BackgroundWorker class, to have in integrate with the Amazon S3 TransferUtiltyUploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent method.
My apologies for not being clear on all this...I've been slamming my head on this same issue for days and can't seem to find a solution to it, short of just doing away with the progress bar altogether...which I hate to do, hate not seeing that the app is still processing the files.

Comment: @user1078155 - I see that you are using an `int` as the `PercentDone`.  How about putting a check in the `UpdateProgressBar` function to see if this value actually changed.  I'm not sure how you are calculating the `PercentDone`, but if it doesnt change, it would save you some processing if you didnt call `Invoke`.  See my updated example.

Comment: I put that in, makes sense to not have the progress bar try to update unless the percent done has changed.  But it doesn't fix the problem:  Small file works fine, large file freezes up everything.