# C# - AWS S3 uploading a file using PutObject or TransferUtility.Upload method. Which is the better way to go with?

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-s3

I know there are two methods available to upload files in AWS S3 (i.e. PutObject and  TransferUtility.Upload). Can someone please explain which one to use?

FYI, I have files ranging from 1kb to 250MB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based in [Amazon docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility.htm), I would stick with `TransferUtility.Upload`:

> Provides a high level utility for managing transfers to and from Amazon S3.
>
> TransferUtility provides a simple API for uploading content to and downloading content from Amazon S3. It makes extensive use of Amazon S3 multipart uploads to achieve enhanced throughput, performance, and reliability.
>
> When uploading large files by specifying file paths instead of a stream, TransferUtility uses multiple threads to upload multiple parts of a single upload at once. When dealing with large content sizes and high bandwidth, this can increase throughput significantly.

But please be aware of possible concurrency issues and the recommendation about using BeginUpload (the asynchronous version), like in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362049/amazon-s3-transferutility-upload-hangs-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you think I need to use BeginUpload in asp.net app or I can just use the normal Upload method?

Comment: You're welcome. It really depends on whether you want the upload to be synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: If I am doing asynchronously how the status will be shown in ASP.Net app? Is there any example available?

Comment: Please have a look into [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx) from MSDN on sync vs. async.

Comment: TransferUtility.Upload is 4 times faster than PutObject when I uploaded a 110MB file, TransferUtility.Upload is the way to go

Answer (score 11):

> Amazon deprecated the S3 **Transfer Manager** and migrated to the new
>   **Transfer Utility**.The Transfer Utility is a simple interface for handling the most common uses of S3.It has a single constructor, which
>   requires an instance of **AmazonS3Client**. Working with it is so easy
>   and let the develpers perform all operations with less code.

**Following are key features of using Transfer Utility over Transfer Manager**

- When uploading large files, TransferUtility uses **multiple threads** to
  upload multiple parts of a single upload at once.When dealing with
  large content sizes and **high bandwidth**, this can **increase throughput**
  significantly.TransferUtility detects if a file is large and switches into
  multipart upload mode. The **multipart upload** gives the benefit of
  better performance as the parts can be uploaded simultaneously as
  well, and if there is an error, only the individual part has to be
  retried.
- Mostly we people try to upload large files on S3 that take too much
  time to upload,at those situations we required progress information
  such as the total number of **bytes transferred** and **remaining amount of
  data** to transfer.To track current progress of transfer with the
  Transfer Manager, developers pass an **S3ProgressListener** callback to
  upload or download, which periodically fires the method below.
- Pausing transfers using the Transfer Manager is not possible with
  stream based uploads or downloads.But Transfer Utility provide us
  **pause and resume** option, it also has one single-file-based method for
  uploads, and downloads.

> transferUtility.upload(MY_BUCKET,OBJECT_KEY,FILE_TO_UPLOAD)
>   transferUtility.download(MY_BUCKET,OBJECT_KEY,FILE_TO_UPLOAD)

- The Transfer Manager only requires the INTERNET permission. However,
  since the Transfer Utility **automatically detects network state** and
  **pauses/resumes transfers** based on the network state
  pause functionality to the Transfer Utility is easy, since all transfers can be paused and resumed.A transfer is paused because of a loss of network connectivity, it will automatically be resumed and there is no action you need to take.Transfers that are automatically paused and waiting for network connectivity will have the state.Additionally, the Transfer Utility stores all of the metadata about transfers to the local SQLite database, so developers do not need to persist anything.

**Note :**
Every thing else is good.But Transfer Utility does not support a copy() API.To accomplish it use **AmazonS3Client** class **copyObject()** method.

Comment: it was quite a simple and briefly explain thumbs up  .

Comment: How to pause and resume uploading file on Amazon s3?

Comment: @SantoshKokatnur : Code will not be shown here in proper format. Sorry for that but here is what you want .....TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download("bucket_name", "key", file);
int id = observer.getId();

transferUtility.pause(id);
transferUtility.resume(id);

Comment: TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download("bucket_name", "key", file); 
int id = observer.getId(); 
transferUtility.pause(id); 
transferUtility.resume(id);

Comment: @SantoshKokatnur I had already sent it two times before.It seems like plain text but actually its un-indented code.Just copy it and put into you IDE work environment and use it.

Comment: @Malik **Thank you**

Comment: @MalikKhalil you did not tell about PutObject at all. It was a comparison right.

Comment: @MalikKhalil Will you be able to post a sample code for resume()?