# Amazon S3 TransferUtility.Upload hangs after one file uploaded

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

Hi everyone I'm trying to upload .csv file in amazon S3 it works fine till one file was uploaded, but after then system hangs and nothing will happen next.

I was refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362049/amazon-s3-transferutility-upload-hangs-in-c-sharp) but not get right solution.

If you have right way then please let me aware.

My code is her

```
public static void UploadScreenShot(string FullFilePath, string DestPath, string FileName)
{
        try
        {
                    TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));
                    fileTransferUtility.Upload(FullFilePath, existingBucketName, DestPath +FileName);
                    fileTransferUtility.Dispose();
        }
        catch{}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having this on AWS SDK 2.3, it works fine on AWS SDK 2.2.2.  I still havn't figured out why its locking up.
I locks up in this method on line

```
var response = await base.InvokeAsync<T>(executionContext).ConfigureAwait(false); 

public override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> InvokeAsync<T>(IExecutionContext executionContext)
        {
            executionContext.RequestContext.Metrics.AddProperty(Metric.AsyncCall, true);
            try
            {
                executionContext.RequestContext.Metrics.StartEvent(Metric.ClientExecuteTime);
                var response = await base.InvokeAsync<T>(executionContext).ConfigureAwait(false);    
                return response;                              
            }
            finally
            {
                executionContext.RequestContext.Metrics.StopEvent(Metric.ClientExecuteTime);
                this.LogMetrics(executionContext);
            }            
        }
```

I ended up filing a bug on their github. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/137

Comment: @BharatPrajapati what does that mean?  "it works fine with threading" ?

Comment: if you assign unique thread for every single file then it's not goes hangs. and application works fine.

Comment: Amazon fixed this issue in v2.3.1.0 of their SDK

Comment: @user384080 thank you so much for viewing this question. I recently solved this problem by using Thread execution.